# Face Detection without cutting the head

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection, dlib, deepface

I have tried several libraries and ways to detect faces and export them as an image.
The problem is that all the algorithms are cutting a lot of the head.
Example from the [deepface](https://github.com/serengil/deepface) doc:

[image]

While I want something like:

[image]

Is there a way of doing so? Or adding "padding" to the coordinates in a smart way?

I get **start** and **end** points.

Comment: You are cropping the original image, right? Just add a margin/offset of n pixels to the bounding box before slicing and that should give you what you expect.

Comment: But if the face is upside down that would do the exact opposite. Because I always get stat coordinate and end coordinate. What is the algorithm to always increase the rectangle?

Comment: Perhaps it's sufficient to expand (dilate) the rectangle by some percentage after your search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I build a function to do that with simple math:

```
def increase_rectangle_size(points: list[int64,int64,int64,int64], increase_percentage: int):
    delta_x = (points[0] - points[2]) * increase_percentage // 100
    delta_y = (points[1] - points[3]) * increase_percentage // 100

    new_points = [points[0] + delta_x, points[1] + delta_y, points[2] - delta_x, points[3] - delta_y]

    return [(i > 0) * i for i in new_points]  # Negative numbers to zeros.
```

What it basically does is increase the distance between the two dots (On the dots 'line').

I don't want less than 0 values so I checked for negative numbers at the end of the function. I do not care if I get out of the frame (for bigger numbers).

I get the two points as a list ([x1, y1, x2, y2]) because this is how the library I use handles that but you can change it to 2 points of course.